# Chrome takes about 10% of CPU without any activity from the user or an add-on

Tags: google-chrome, cpu

Here is the case. Chrome is not open (no chrome.exe appears on my task manager). I launch Chrome. Just a default empty tab. No default page. I click on the 'View background pages' and I see the following (CPU list):

Browser: 4-13%
Tab: New Tab: 0%
Extentions: Pinterest: 0%
Extentions: LastPass: 0%
(other extentions) : 0%
GPU Process: 0%
Plug-in: NLastPass : 0%

And the CPU utilisation remains there as long as I have chrome open. I see similar status on Windows Task Manager.

Why is that!?

I'm using latest version of Chrome 25.0.1364.172 on a Windows 8 Enterprise fully updated. Quad core machine with 8Gb of RAM and SSD.

Comment: I also tried to disable all addons, eventhough they are not reported by chrome consuming any CPU. No change. Launching chrome results in 8-11% of CPU being utilized.

Answer (score 1):

It seems we will never know. I uninstalled (and cleared all user adata) and reinstalled Chrome, added again the same addons I had before.

Now it's fine. Slight or no CPU usage when idle (no user, addon or page activity).

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, it's because of power management. CPU usage is expressed as a percentage of your CPU's *current* capability. Power management drastically reduces that to the point that 10% is practically no CPU at all.

If you launch some other process that puts even a moderate load on the CPU, you'll probably see that percentage drop. It's not because Chrome is doing less, it's because your CPU's performance has been increased.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get it. Neither Internet Explorer nor any other application is consuming CPU resources when my laptop is idle and there is no maintenance job in progress. Chrome (itself, not web pages or addons) consumes about 8% of the CPU all the time, reducing this way the life of my battery. That is regardless whether I'm using the Power Save or Balanced power scheme in Windows or not.

Comment: Did you confirm that this CPU usage takes the CPU out of idle and actually impacts your battery?

Comment: But the question is why Chrome (not the pages, not addons, not flash) is using my CPU when no other application is doing the same. And it's not every now and then. It's consistent. Always! Windows task manager reports 10% of CPU utilized all the time!